# Media player in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I am using the media player in Windows Phone 7 to play the music in the phone song collection. But when it play the music they will be an exception and the error is stating

> FrameworkDispatcher.Update has not been called. Regular FrameworkDispatcher.Update calls are necessary for fire and forget sound effects and framework events to function correctly.

How should i go about modifying my code?

```
private void songBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var ml = new MediaLibrary())
    {
        foreach (var song in ml.Songs)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(song.Artist + " " + song.Name);
            MessageBox.Show(song.Artist + " " + song.Name);
        }
        MediaPlayer.Play(ml.Songs[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call

```
FrameworkDispatcher.Update()
```

whenever you make a call to an XNA media library
so your code should look like this

```
using (var ml = new MediaLibrary())
{

  foreach (var song in ml.Songs)
  {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(song.Artist + " " + song.Name);
      MessageBox.Show(song.Artist + " " + song.Name);

  }
  FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
  MediaPlayer.Play(ml.Songs[0]);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to deteremine when the song ended then repeat playing the song??

Comment: use the MediaPlayer.MediaStateChanged event to get notifications about playing state changes, then you can use the MediaPlayer.State to get the current state, another alternative is to set the MediaPlayer.IsRepeating to true so you don't need to monitor state changes

Answer (score 2):

The error is occouring because you're using the XNA Framework in a regular Windows Phone 7 application.

If you read the error description, you would gotten this link to MSDN: [Enable XNA Framework Events in Windows Phone Applications](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=193853) , which explains precisely what to do.