# Want to retrive Song file name and path from Song instance

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using the SongCollection library to retrieve the list of songs and then try to create an AudioTrack instance to play the song in the background. For this I need to fetch the complete file name of the song and then pass the URI to the background audio agent.

Is there any way to retrieve the complete file name from the Song instance obtained from SongCollection ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but you can just use the [MediaPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.aspx) class to play songs from a SongCollection. The MediaPlayer class runs in the background automatically and should give the same experience of what you're trying to do.

As a side note, there is currently no way of retrieving the Song's URI, so it can only be accessed (and played) via the MediaPlayer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I had tried the MediaPlayer class by calling MediaPlayer.Play(song) when I click the play button. But after that the control waits for sometime before it comes out and then I saw a crash. I was thinking that the crash may be because of the fact that the UI is stuck for more than 10 secs. So to avoid that I created a AudioPlayerAgent and wanted to play the song as a background task

Comment: Is there a chance the the MP3 you tried to play has DRM? Try using a DRM-free MP3. The Song shouldn't crash, so you could put it in a Try..Catch and see if an exception is thrown.

Comment: No it is not a drm file. I dont remember the crash message, but I remember that once the MediaPlayer.Play(song) was called, the control took sometime to come to the next line and then I saw the control jumping to some crash handler code. I will re-check the scenario once more and provide more details.

Comment: Hi, the error message that is thrown when I execute the code is "InvalidOperationException was unhandled. FrameworkDispatcher.Update calls are necessary for fire and forget sound effects and framework events to function correctly". I saw a similar post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807963/media-player-in-windows-phone-7. Will try the solution proposed.

Comment: Yes, the FrameworkDispatcher is most likely the problem. Whenever you use the MediaPlayer class in a Silverlight app, you need to include it.

Comment: Yes it is working now. I need to call the update API quite frequently, otherwise I dont get the XNA events on time!  One more question, is there any way to add songs to MediaLibrary ?

Comment: No, you can't add songs to the MediaLibrary, only pictures at the moment.

Comment: Ok.. so is there any public directory in wp7 emulator sdk that an user can put his songs and play using his own music player? I dont want to copy the songs in the isolatedStorage of my application but play it from a public directory?