# Playing music in Silverlight + XNA application

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, audio, xna

I have several issues with playing music in a Silverlight+XNA combined application. It has several Silverlight pages and the "game" page rendered in XNA.

First, I added the following code to the OnNavigatedTo event of the main Silverlight page:

```
var song = (Application.Current as App).Content.Load<Song>("Music/Menu");
MediaPlayer.Play(song);
MediaPlayer.Volume = 0.9f;
MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
```

The music starts playing, however the application fails with the following exception that has no evident callstack hints:

```
InvalidOperationException occured
FrameworkDispatcher.Update has not been called. Regular FrameworkDispatcher.Update calls are necessary for fire and forget sound effects and framework events to function correctly.
```

Secondly, I have a few Silverlight-based windows rendered using `UIElementRenderer`. When the need arises, I change the control's `IsEnabled` flag to true and start drawing it on the screen. This makes the music stop playing with a fadeout for no apparent reason and it wouldn't even start back when I close the Silverligh window.

Navigating from the frame and back to it makes things even worse. The same call to `MediaPlayer.Play(song)` says that the song has been disposed, even though I load it from the `ContentManager` anew.

Comment: Read the exception message - it explains exactly how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807963/media-player-in-windows-phone-7) question — answer is pretty clear. In short, you have to call `FrameworkDispatcher.Update()` before using XNA media libraries.

Comment: Thanks! That did help for the first part. However, I'm still puzzled with the fact that `UIElementRenderer`-based window stops the music.

Comment: I think you sould create a different question — mixing questions is not a good practice.