# Windows phone 8 on emulator - why can't I play audio files?

Tags: mp3, media-player, windows-phone-8, filenotfoundexception

I'm converting an app that was written in Silverlight, and so far I've succeeded in solving all of the problems, except for one:

For some reason, the emulator refuses to play any audio files of the app, and it doesn't even throw an exception. I've checked, and in the ringtone category it can make sounds.

The original code was :

```
<Grid x:Name="sharedFullScreenFilePathContainer"
Tag="{Binding StringFormat=\{0\},Converter={StaticResource fullScreenImageConverter}}">

    <Image x:Name="fullScreenImage" Stretch="Fill"
Source="{Binding ElementName=sharedFullScreenFilePathContainer,Path=Tag, StringFormat=../Assets/images/\{0\}.jpg}"
ImageFailed="onFullScreenImageFailedToLoad" MouseLeftButtonDown="onPressedOnFullScreenImage" />

    <MediaElement x:Name="mediaPlayer" AutoPlay="True"
Source="{Binding ElementName=sharedFullScreenFilePathContainer,Path=Tag, StringFormat=../Assets/sounds/\{0\}.wma}" />
</Grid>
```

so, the image that I set to this item's context is really shown, but the sound that really exists on the path I set to it doesn't play (I've checked in the "Bin" folder).

I've tried to use code instead of xaml, but I still have the same problem.

I've tried this (though it's usually used for background music):

```
AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(new Uri("../Assets/sounds/" + fileToOpen, UriKind.Relative), "", "", "", null);
BackgroundAudioPlayer player = BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance;
player.Track = audioTrack;
player.Play();
```

It didn't play anything, and also didn't throw any exception.

I've also tried the next code, but it throws an exception (file not found exception) probably because I don't call it right:

```
Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("@Assets/sounds/" + fileToOpen);
SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
effect.Play();
```

I've also tried using wma files but it also didn't work.

I also tried to play with the "copy to output directory" parameter of the mp3 files (to "always" and "only if new" ) and with the "build action" parameter (to "none" and "content" ). Nothing helps.

Can anyone please help me? I didn't develop for Silverlight/WP for a very long time and I can't find out how to fix it .

Btw, since later I need to know when the sound has finished playing (and also to be able to stop it), I would like to use code anyway. I would be happy if you could also tell me how to do it too (I can ask it on a new post if needed).

---

EDIT: 
ok , i've found out the problem : i kept getting a weird exception when using the **MediaPlayer.Play()** method , and after checking out about the exception , i've found out that it's a known issue , and that i need to call **FrameworkDispatcher.Update();** right before i call the Play() method .

so the solution would be to do something like this:

```
Song song = Song.FromUri(...);
MediaPlayer.Stop(); 
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
MediaPlayer.Play(song);
```

the exception is:

'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll"

i've found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807963/media-player-in-windows-phone-7) .

Now the question is why , and how come I didn't find anything related to it in the demos of windows phone ? Also , i would like to know what this function does .

---

ok , since nobody gave me an answer to both questions , and I still wish to give the bounty , I will ask another question :

If there is really no solution other than using the MediaPlayer class for windows phone , how do i capture the event of finishing playing an audio file ? Even getting the audio file duration doesn't work (keeps returning 0 length , no matter which class i've tried to use) ...

Comment: Have you seen this, it is because you use XNA to play audio! http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff842408.aspx

Comment: Please forgive me . I've written that i'm a newb at WP . Do i have a choice of how to play the audio file ? i only wanted to play it (and stop previous one if needed) . Does it matter much if the app uses XNA ? Is it not a part of the API ? I just really don't know much about this and i can't understand why it has to take so many steps to do something so basic and simple .

Comment: No problem, I just think you have some problem to write the correct reference to the media resource from your application to the MediaElement, it is no big deal to play an audio file on the Windows Phone :-)

Comment: no , i've set it to "content" type and set it to "copy if newer" . that wasn't the problem . the problem was a very weird exception that i still don't understand what it means , and why what i've found fixes it.

Comment: How and why to use properly the FrameworkDispatcher is described here: http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2012/07/solution-for-frameworkdispatcherupdate.html I know, It's a bit pain, but for some functions in WP8 you just have to dig deeper. Not everything is in basic samples.

Comment: Thank you for this . However , I still see so many basic features missing . For example , how would i set an observer to get the event of finishing playing a song via the MediaPlayer object ? or even stop all of the songs (clearing the queue ) ? I can't find a good API and looking at what VS offers me , it seems impossible using the MediaPlayer . Isn't there a good API for playing audio and have some control over it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the MediaElement instead, this can play media files stored in your application, but stops playing when the application stops (you can make some advance chance to your app so it keep running, but it will not work very well)

In your XAML:

```
        <Button x:Name="PlayFile"
                Click="PlayFile_Click_1"
                Content="Play mp3" />
```

In your Code behind:

```
    MediaElement MyMedia = new MediaElement();
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(MyMedia);

        MyMedia.CurrentStateChanged += MyMedia_CurrentStateChanged;
        MyMedia.MediaEnded += MyMedia_MediaEnded;
    }

    void MyMedia_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ended event " + MyMedia.CurrentState.ToString());
        // Set the source to null, force a Close event in current state
        MyMedia.Source = null;
    }

    void MyMedia_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (MyMedia.CurrentState)
        {
            case System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.AcquiringLicense:
                break;
            case System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.Buffering:
                break;
            case System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.Closed:
                break;
            case System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.Individualizing:
                break;
            case System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.Opening:
                break;
            case System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.Paused:
                break;
            case System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.Playing:
                break;
            case System.Windows.Media.MediaElementState.Stopped:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CurrentState event " + MyMedia.CurrentState.ToString());
    }

    private void PlayFile_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Play Awesome music file, stored as content in the Assets folder in your app
        MyMedia.Source = new Uri("Assets/AwesomeMusic.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        MyMedia.Play();
    }
```

Comment: It didn't work . It didn't crash , but also didn't play anything. In fact , that's about the same solution as i used in the beginning when i had a working silverlight project.  Anyway, i've succeeded playing the audio by using MediaPlayer , yet just before playing, i called FrameworkDispatcher.Update() . i've update my question and if any of the current answers won't answer the current question (since i have set a bounty and i do wish to give it in case the answer is worthy) , i will add my own.

Comment: I do not understand why can not play the file from the MediaElement. How do you add the media file to the project? The MediaFile must be added to the project. I had no problem at all playing a large mp3 file from my project!

Comment: On the emulator ? i don't understand why it didn't work for me . i used pure code instead of xml this time . Could you do the same and tell me if it worked for you too ?

Comment: Yes i did in the emulator on Windows 8 + VS2012 + Phone 8 project. Is this the same setup (have also a version with Phone 7.5)? The line of code in my answer (MediaElement) is all i have used, remember to mark your media file as content!!

Comment: So i have no idea . I have windows 8 pro , with VS2012 , and it's a windows phone 8 project too . I didn't do anything special with the installation of VS . have you tried to use pure code instead of xaml ?

Comment: Yes, no problem see my new answer :-), it is properly just because you don not add the MediaElement to page. The MediaElement must "live" in some UI container, otherwise it will not work!

Comment: Unless the MediaElement is explicitly added to the visual tree internally the message pump of the MediaElement doesn't get well... "pumped". One of the side effects of this is that you don't get events reported by the MediaElement. This is actually by design as the MediaElement does derive from a standard XAML control.

Comment: from what I remember MediaElement cannot play audio in the emulator, unless something has changed recently. Also in general in Silverlight apps the MediaElement has to be in the visual tree in order to play audio (you can't just instantiate one from code, it won't play without returning any error)

Answer (score 2):

The BackgroundAudioPlayer can play files **only** from isolated storage or from a remote URI, that is why you can here anything!

If you have your file as resources in your app, you must first copy them to the isolated store, and then make a reference to the file in the isolated store to your BackgroundAudioPlayer.

```
    private void CopyToIsolatedStorage()
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            string[] files = new string[] 
                { "Kalimba.mp3", 
                    "Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3", 
                    "Sleep Away.mp3" };

            foreach (var _fileName in files)
            {
                if (!storage.FileExists(_fileName))
                {
                    string _filePath = "Audio/" + _fileName;
                    StreamResourceInfo resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(_filePath, UriKind.Relative));

                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream file = storage.CreateFile(_fileName))
                    {
                        int chunkSize = 4096;
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[chunkSize];
                        int byteCount;

                        while ((byteCount = resource.Stream.Read(bytes, 0, chunkSize)) > 0)
                        {
                            file.Write(bytes, 0, byteCount);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And then you can make a list of your songs

```
    private static List<AudioTrack> _playList = new List<AudioTrack>
    {
        new AudioTrack(new Uri("Kalimba.mp3", UriKind.Relative), 
                        "Kalimba", 
                        "Mr. Scruff", 
                        "Ninja Tuna", 
                        null),

        new AudioTrack(new Uri("Maid with the Flaxen Hair.mp3", UriKind.Relative), 
                        "Maid with the Flaxen Hair", 
                        "Richard Stoltzman", 
                        "Fine Music, Vol. 1", 
                        null),

        new AudioTrack(new Uri("Sleep Away.mp3", UriKind.Relative), 
                        "Sleep Away", 
                        "Bob Acri", 
                        "Bob Acri", 
                        null),

        // A remote URI
        new AudioTrack(new Uri("http://traffic.libsyn.com/wpradio/WPRadio_29.mp3", UriKind.Absolute), 
                        "Episode 29", 
                        "Windows Phone Radio", 
                        "Windows Phone Radio Podcast", 
                        null)
    };
```

And play your tracks!

```
    private void PlayNextTrack(BackgroundAudioPlayer player)
    {
        if (++currentTrackNumber >= _playList.Count)
        {
            currentTrackNumber = 0;
        }

        PlayTrack(player);
    }

    private void PlayPreviousTrack(BackgroundAudioPlayer player)
    {
        if (--currentTrackNumber < 0)
        {
            currentTrackNumber = _playList.Count - 1;
        }

        PlayTrack(player);
    }

    private void PlayTrack(BackgroundAudioPlayer player)
    {
        // Sets the track to play. When the TrackReady state is received, 
        // playback begins from the OnPlayStateChanged handler.
        player.Track = _playList[currentTrackNumber];
    }
```

Comment: but won't it take 2 times the space this way ? isn't it a waste of both time and space ?

Comment: Yes, but it is the only way if you want to use the BackgroundAudioPlayer with files you have in your application.

Comment: Isn't there any other way to play a sound ? One that won't require such a wasteful action? I've written about the BackgroundAudioPlayer only as something that i've tried , not something that i think should be used. Of course , i also wonder why this class doesn't support playing files on the app , but maybe i just don't know its purpose well , as i'm a newb on Windows Phone.

Comment: The BackgroundAudioPlayer plays audio from an Isosolated store or from an uri, because it can continue playing the file  when you close down your application. The BackgroundAudioPlayer has no access to the Applications resources and therefor you must put the media file to a location shared by the application and the BackgroundAudioPlayer.

Comment: You could use the MediaElement instead, this can play mp3 files directly from you application.             this.MyMedia.Source = new Uri("Assets/AwesomeMusic.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            this.MyMedia.Play(); I post another answer below!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the MediaElement to work from your code you can do something like this!

```
        MediaElement me = new MediaElement();
        // Must add the MediaElement to some UI container on 
        // your page or some UI-control, otherwise it will not play!
        this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(me);
        me.Source = new Uri("Assets/AwesomeMusic.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        me.Play();
```

Comment: hmmm ... now that i also try to put a super short xaml tag for it , it works as i've tried in the beginning. maybe the path was wrong . please merge this answer to the previous one , and also try answering this: how do i get notified when the sound has finished being played ? by using CurrentStateChanged , i get the event of being paused multiple times instead of once. also , why does it even need to be in the UI ?

Comment: I will merge the answer. I think it is because the MediaElement is an UI component and need the UI thread for working!

Comment: Well the question was how come . I mean , how could something that is not visual at all must be in the ui , instead of at least being optional . I also asked how come i get the MediaElementState.Paused multiple times even though i play a single audio file .

Comment: by design as the MediaElement does derive from a standard XAML control! I don't know why the Pause event is pumped mutiple times, must be a bug!

Comment: ok . anyway , please merge the answers so that i could give you the bounty . i still don't know what i did wrong . Currently , my theory is that i simply didn't set the path right.

Comment: Thanks i merge the answer yesterday, plus some more!

Answer (score 0):

Audio track plays audio files stored in isolated storage or streamed over the internet.

Comment: ok , so how do i play mp3 files , and how come it worked fine on both silverlight and wpf , yet here it didn't ?

Answer (score 0):

Playing audio files stored within the application package works fine for me. I got files named like "Alarm01.wma" in project folder Resources\Alarms. I then play these sounds like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
...
Song s = Song.FromUri("alarm", new Uri(@"Resources/Alarms/Alarm01.wma", UriKind.Relative));
MediaPlayer.Play(s);
```

Also don't forget to reference **Microsoft.Xna.Framework** library.

I guess it should work fine for mp3 files and files stored in IsolatedStorage as well.

Comment: What's the first parameter for  ? Can't i just tell it to play a file ? Also , how come i need to add the reference , instead of VS to offer me since it's built into the libraries that it supports ? Obviously , nobody can remember all of the classes&functions provided by the libraries that were installed , right? On eclipse, each time you use a class that wasn't imported , it offers suggestions for you. is there at least a list of the essential libraries installed by default and their classes ?

Comment: Now that i've tried to add the reference , i can't find it . How could it be ? Do i really have to install a special component to make a windows phone app support playing audio ?

Comment: In your Visual Studio project just click on References -> Add reference -> Microsoft.Xna.Framework. Visual studio offers you automatic inclusion of usings, but only for types in currently referenced libraries.

Comment: Yes i know that , but i can't find there the "Microsoft.Xna.Framework"  library . In fact , there are only very several items there (no matter which category i choose) . About the annoyance i've written , you actually confirmed that it exists - the developer needs to know exactly which reference to use for each class he needs to use , as contrary to eclipse which offers it automatically . I think it's a very basic feature that VS lacks.

Comment: found the solution to the problem by myself . updated the question . please check it out .