# How to play a music from music+video hub in AudioPlaybackAgent?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I want to play a song which is stored in `Music+video Hub` in `AudioPlaybackAgent`.

I can get songs by this way:

```
MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
var songs = mediaLibrary.Songs;
```

but this songs are of type `Song` and `BackgroundAudioPlayer` accepts sounds of type `AudioTrack`:

```
BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = ..
```

Question: how can I play a song from music hub in `AudioPlaybackAgent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here: [Windows phone 8 on emulator - why can't I play audio files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418276/windows-phone-8-on-emulator-why-cant-i-play-audio-files) see the answer number 3 (Author:Frederik Winstrup Johansen). He also added a good sample about playing AudioTracks

> The BackgroundAudioPlayer can play files only from isolated storage or
>   from a remote URI, that is why you can here anything!
>
> If you have your file as resources in your app, you must first copy
>   them to the isolated store, and then make a reference to the file in
>   the isolated store to your BackgroundAudioPlayer.